# Dedicate GPU usage only to Tensorflow - Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

Recently successfully configured my GPU with Tensorflow, in order to minimize the training time of 16-iterative neural models of 150 epochs each from 12 hours on CPU. I haven't tested yet the GPU's performance in all 16 iterations, although I suppose it would take much less time than 12 hours (my guess).

Last night I run the model training for 1 iteration of 150 epochs and the model took approximately 30 minutes to be trained. However, I noticed from my system's vital rates that the GPU was only utilized for a 10% of its capacity, contrary to the 90% CPU capacity used to train the model for 150 epochs. Even though, my GPU is correctly configured with CUDA and CuDNN  it uses only 10% of its capacity for Tensorflow. How can I configure the Tensorflow to use 100% of my GPU capacity and free all the capacity of CPU?

**Configuration regarding GPU**

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib 

print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

stdout 1:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 10937863864393548495
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 4849834393
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 7632083706462665444
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"
]
```

```
import tensorflow as tf

print("Version: ", tf.__version__)
print("Eager mode: ", tf.executing_eagerly())
print("Hub version: ", hub.__version__)
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') else "NOT AVAILABLE")
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

stdout 2:

```
TensorFlow version:  2.1.0
Version:  2.1.0
Eager mode:  True
Hub version:  0.7.0
GPU is available
Num GPUs Available:  1
```

```
from platform import python_version

print("Python version installed: ", python_version())
```

stdout 3:

```
Python version installed:  3.7.4
```

```
!nvcc --version
```

stdout 4:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:12:52_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

CuDNN version: cudnn-10.1-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32

Comment: It is not a configuration setting, it depends on how much computation your model requires. This is a common misconception, you might try to increase the batch size so more compute is needed

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thank you for the reply. Actually I am searching a lot about it and it all ends down to the computations. I have tested different programs running on GPU and they seem both to work and also executed on less time. OK if you say so about the computations I can bear with it.